# how to read property form Object?

Tags: spring-integration

I want to return an `Object` from a method , and i want to read the properties of that `Object` in `<int:jpa-Parameter>`.

```
<int-jpa:parameter name="responseDate" expression="payload['responseDate']/>
```

this work fine if i return `Map`. but for `Object` or `List<Map>` i got exception

> Indexing into type ......... not supported.

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

If the payload is a `Map` you can use the `MapAccessor` - `payload['foo']`

If the payload is an object with property `foo`, use `payload.foo` (calls `getFoo()`)

If the payload is a list of objects, you would need to index into the list to look at the property on an instance in the list `payload.get(0).foo`.

`payload.x` references a property on the list - such as `payload.size()`.